# BerkeleyDb : safe removing files of environment

Tags: berkeley-db

I use BerkeleyDb in a project.
I have some environments composed by several file. Sometimes, **I need to remove some of these files**.

When I remove file with the filesystem, opening the environment raise an error **No such file or directory**.

Do exists a **way to safely removing a file** in BerkeleyDb environment ?

Answer (score 0):

To remove a database, you need to be absolutely certain that no references to the database exist in the environment.  The most foolproof way to do this is as follows:

1. Use `db->remove()` to remove the database from inside your application.
2. Use `dbenv->txn_checkpoint()` to flush all changes, checkpoint the log, and then flush the log.
3. Use `dbenv->txn_checkpoint()` with the `DB_FORCE` flag to push one more checkpoint through, ensuring that when the environment is recovered that it doesn't attempt to recover databases that predated the last checkpoint.

Step 3 sounds insane, I know.  And maybe it isn't needed any more.  But it certainly was needed in the not-too-distant past.  Certainly steps 1 and 2 are needed.  You'll need to experiment to see if step 3 is necessary for your application.